# Carga de Div externo con funcion javascript externa

Tags: javascript, div

Hola tengo este página que contiene el siguiente código, actualiza el Div cada segundo, es una especie de "Chat", los mensajes se van cargando automaticamente (si los hay) en la misma ventana. "Texto.asp" hace una serie de comprobaciones para emitir un sonido en caso de haber mensajes nuevos, hasta aquí todo va bien, funciona perfectamente, el problema (o lo que deseo) es que cuando haya mensajes nuevos, el scroll se deslice automaticamente hasta abajo (como un chat):

Página "Inicio.asp"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function actualizar(){location.reload(true);}
setInterval("loadDoc()",1000);
</script>

<div id="demo"></div>
<Body onLoad="loadDoc()">

<script>
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
this.responseText;
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "Texto.asp", true);
xhttp.send();
}
</Script>
```

Esto funciona correctamente, mi problema viene aquí:

Texto.asp tiene una consulta a la base de datos, si el resultado es el requerido emite un sonido (sin problemas) y deseo que el Scroll se deslice hacía abajo:

Archivo Texto.asp:

```
<Script>
function jumpScroll() {
window.scroll(0,1000000050);
}
</Script>
```

Pero Texto.asp no lo ejecuta, como puedo hacer para ejecutar esa función.

Si lo coloco en "Inicio.asp" funciona correctamente, pero necesito que se ejecute desde Texto.asp despúes de realizar ciertas comprobaciones, esas comprobaciones las realiza cada segundo.
Gracias!

Comment: Además de que seguramente estés preguntando por JavaScript (Java no es lo mismo que JavaScript), ¿cuál es el "resultado requerido"? ¿qué intentaste? ¿probaste agregar una llamada a la función después de cambiarle el texto al elemento `#demo`? Sería bueno que edites tu pregunta y agregues al menos las respuestas a esto o una descripción más en detalle

Comment: Listo, creo que por las prisas no supe explicarme bien, está editado mi post.

Comment: Probablemente lo que necesites es poner el `window.scroll(0,1000000050);` después del `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
this.responseText;` que está en el `Inicio.asp`. Pero no si si ante cualquier respuesta querés ejecutar el scroll. Porque decís "si el resultado es el requerido", no se cual es ese resultado. El punto es que el código JS no puede estar en el archivo nuevo, la lógica tiene que estar en "Inicio.asp" y según la respuesta obtenida por AJAX se ejecuta o no una determinada acción.

Comment: Ya lo intenté y si funciona, pero se actualiza igual cada segundo, de esta manera cuando movemos el Scroll hacía arriba luego luego lo baja (pues actualiza cada segundo), la comprobación que hago es solo ver si hay mensajes nuevos. Alguna idea que tengas? No es precisamente un chat, pero funciona similar

Comment: La comprobación de si hay mensajes nuevos la hacés desde el backend? Si es así, entonces deberías responder -desde el backend- de una manera si hay mensajes nuevos y de otra si no los hay. Esa respuesta la lees desde JS y de manera condicional ejecutas, o no,el `scroll()`. No manejo ASP, pero sin ver el código del backend, más no te puedo ayudar.